# If parent div has specific class toggle another div using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display a `div` if a parent `div` has a specific `class` using JS?

In the code below I would like to display the `div` with `class` **.hidden-gray** only if parent div below has `class` **.matched** and child `div` has `class` **.gray**.

And, the `div` with `class` **.hidden-purple** only if parent below div has `class` **.matched** and child `div` has `class` **.purple**.

```
<div class="hidden-gray">
Display this div only if parent div has class .matched AND child div has class .gray
</div>

<div class="hidden-purple">
Display this div only if parent div has class .matched AND child div has class .purple
</div>

<div class="turn matched" id="1">
    <div class="tile gray">
        <div class="face front" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/336x221">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      
<div class="turn matched" id="2">
    <div class="tile purple">
        <div class="face front" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/336x221">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .mystyle {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px;
 background-color: coral;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.turn {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.hidden-gray {
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: gray;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden-purple {
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: purple;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Many thanks!

**[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3178cu2/2/)**

Comment: Hey actually I can't understand this problem. Which is the "parent div" of `.hidden-purple?`

Comment: this  div that ha class a child div with class purple <div class="turn matched" id="2">
    <div class="tile purple"> @Musafiroon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. Here's the JS code I added:

```
let x = document.getElementById("1");
let y = document.getElementById("2");
let firstChildx = x.children;  
let firstChildy = y.children; 

if (x.className.indexOf('matched') != '-1' && firstChildx[0].className.indexOf('gray')!= '-1') {
let hideg = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-gray");
hideg[0].style.display = 'block';
}

if (y.className.indexOf('matched') != '-1' && firstChildy[0].className.indexOf('purple')!= '-1' ) {
let hideg = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-purple");
hideg[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

I set `.hidden-gray`and `.hidden-purple` to `display:none;` and then used the js code to check through the class names of the parent div and the first child of the parent div and if it matched the criteria I set the display back to block.

And here it is working:

```js
let x = document.getElementById("1");
let y = document.getElementById("2");
let firstChildx = x.children;  
let firstChildy = y.children; 

if (x.className.indexOf('matched') != '-1' && firstChildx[0].className.indexOf('gray')!= '-1') {
let hideg = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-gray");
hideg[0].style.display = 'block';
}

if (y.className.indexOf('matched') != '-1' && firstChildy[0].className.indexOf('purple')!= '-1' ) {
let hideg = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-purple");
hideg[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.turn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hidden-gray {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.hidden-purple {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-gray">
Display this div only if parent div has class .matched and child div has class .gray
</div>

<div class="hidden-purple">
Display this div only if parent div has class .matched and child div has class .gray
</div>


<div class="turn matched" id="1">
        <div class="tile gray">
            <div class="face front" style="background-color: transparent;">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/336x221">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="turn" id="2">
        <div class="tile purple">
            <div class="face front" style="background-color: transparent;">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/336x221">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi John :) If I run the code both Purple and Gray div are visible but the purple div should be hidden, right? Because this div does not contains the class .matched

`<div class="turn" id="2">
    <div class="tile purple">
    <div class="face front" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/336x221">
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>`

Comment: @A-creative I apologize, I forgot to add part of the if statement. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/rNGPWjE).

First, add `.hidden` class to hide your `hidden-*` div.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

and add js (check the link).